# Intellij-IDEA: How to put path to a method in my clipboard

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Intellij has this cool feature where if you type `ctrl+alt+c`, it copies the absolute path of the file your cursor is in to your clipboard.  I want something similar, but instead of the file path I want the path to the method my cursor is on.  For example, look at this class:

```
package com.sandbox;

public class Sandbox {


    public void doSomething() {

    }
}
```

If I put my cursor on/in `doSomething()`, I'd like to press some keyboard command that will put "com.sandbox.Sandbox#doSomething()" into my clipboard.  If my cursor is in the method, it would be even better if it could put this into my clipboard: "com.sandbox.Sandbox#doSomething():line 45" as the line my cursor was on when I typed the command.

Here's why I want this: I often write emails/instant message other developers and need to tell them to "look at this".  It's very easy to get the method name because I'm usually already there.  But then I need to scroll up to the class name to tell them the class and I lose my place on the method.  I do this often enough in a day that I think I could get some benefit into automating this process.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is "Copy Reference" which should do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Actually "Copy Reference" is very close to that: By default `Ctrl+Alt+Shift-C`.
Note that `Ctrl-Shift-A` (Find Action) is your friend and will show you the above link, too.

This method will not add the line number, though.